# Is my Vue.js computed function recursive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue computed function and would like to know if there is a recursion in my code.

I have some comma seperated states within my prop `this.searchQuery['by-multiple-states']`. My computed function `statesSearchQuery` should be a 'wrapper' for my prop, it should just give me a way to work with my prop not as a string but as a array.

The getter just returns the states as array. The setter should toggle a given 'val'. If within the array, remove it, else add it. Finaly apply the changes on the prop itself.

Because the getter and setter is both called with `this.statesSearchQuery` and the getter is used within the first line of my setter, I'm not sure if there would be a weird interaction. Could someone enlighten me about this situation?

```js
computed: {
  statesSearchQuery: {
    get() {
      return this.searchQuery['by-multiple-states'].split(',').filter(t => t !== '');
    },
    set(val) {
      let state = this.statesSearchQuery;

      if (state.includes(val)) {
        state = state.filter(t => t !== val);
      } else {
        state.push(val);
      }

      this.searchQuery['by-multiple-states'] = state.join(',');
    },
  },
},
```

Update: In retrospect, I can rephrase the question. Is it ok to use the getter of a computed function in the setter of the same?

Comment: It surely is. You're mutating a computed inside itself. This especially doesn't make sense because a getter returns a new value each time it's accessed

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for your feedback, but I don't get it? Would my `this.statesSearchQuery` within the first line, not just an equivalent of `this.searchQuery['by-multiple-states'].split(',').filter(t => t !== '');`? Additionally I can't see a mutation, I just read out the value? And assigning my prop a new value (in the last line) is valid as I see it. Please correct me if I misunderstand.

Comment: `get` returns a new array each time it's called. And it's called when it's mutated in set. It's mutated here `state.push`. I'd advise to use a watcher for side effects instead